# Facebook API - cache response on server

Tags: facebook, caching, mongodb, node.js, express

I've got an app/site that makes a few calls out to the Facebook API upon specific user interaction. I was wondering what the best approach is for caching the responses from some of these API calls on the server.

My current setup is node.js running Express and mongoDB for storage. Should I just shove the API response into mongo with a timestamp, and before making future API calls check in there first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like redis (http://www.redis.io) or memcached ([http://memcached.org/](http://www.memcached.org)) for your caching needs. Make the key a md5 hash of whatever api call you're making and check your cache if the key exists before you hit the api.

Comment: Nice Jeff, will look into redis then since my deployment environment supports it out of the box. You think it would make sense then to swap mongo entirely for redis (I'm currently not doing anything fancy in mongo), or do you usually resort to redis only for caching needs?

Comment: I'm a fan of redis. If you're not doing anything fancy and can make redis do what you need, then redis will be much much faster than mongo could ever be (memory vs disk).

Comment: Cool, will try it out first for the caching needs and then perhaps later on for more. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: For this type of stuff mongo will serve it's data almost exclusively from memory as well (at least, it would do so as much as redis could, but the latter will be a little faster). If you have mongo in place already then adding another tech with almost completely functional overlap seems like a bit of a waste to me. I'd benchmark that options first and only explore alternatives if you are not meeting your performance requirements.